# QT deployment doesn't work missing entry point

Tags: qt

I'm working on my second application in QT and i'm trying to deploy a rough copy for testing. It would not run on a test computer, runs with no problems on mine, giving the error "Procedure Entry Point _ZdaPVJ not found in QT5core.dll". So to make sure that was not my program messing things up, i created a blank test application, compile it for release, moved the test.exe to a different location, run windeployqt --release test.exe, it created all the dependencies and folders. clicked on test.exe run with no problem. grabbed the folder recently created took it to the other computer and go the same error.
Is there something that i have forgotten since i compile my first application? Did i changed some setup somewhere without realizing it?
frustrated...

Comment: Please provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: ?? Is an empty application, as in you open QT Creator and click on new application and compile. Nothing added. Don't know what else should i add.

Comment: I have gotten advice to revise my question, because was not clear and I'm in danger to be banned from the site. English is not my first language and the questions look ok to me. If you could give me a hint of what i need to revise i will happily do that. I have more problem with QT but now i'm afraid to ask.

Comment: Perhaps try to rephrase the question to focus on the "Driver not loaded" problem you mention below. It seems that is your "real" problem at this point. Perhaps also check this answer: [QT example executables won't run, missing QT5Cored.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28732602/qt-example-executables-wont-run-missing-qt5cored-dll).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can check if your problem is related to different versions of the dll existing on your system and the wrong one is being loaded:

- [QT Release build DLL procedure entry point error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11694140/qt-release-build-dll-procedure-entry-point-error)
- https://forum.qt.io/topic/26707/the-procedure-entry-point-cound-not-be-located-in-the-dynamic-link-library

As is suggested in the latter link above (towards the bottom), you could try to use [**dependency walker**](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to determine from where the dll is loaded. Or use static linking with the licensing issues that causes (also see the latter link above).

And throwing in a final link on using **Qt's Window's Deployment tool**: [Qt deployment; the procedure entry point ... could not be located](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21426326/qt-deployment-the-procedure-entry-point-could-not-be-located)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did the following, grabbed the Qt5Core.dll from my other application and it worked. So definitely i have a conflict between dll's. Now my problem is, and i'm sure is related, if i run the application from the deployment folder i get an error Driver not loaded when trying to connect to the database. I'm missing a driver, or wrong driver, don't know how to troubleshoot.

Comment: I am not a Qt expert, I was just trying to add some pointers, but how about trying the [Qt Window's Deployment tool](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html#the-windows-deployment-tool)? My experience is that such tools pull in too many dependencies, but maybe worth a try?

Comment: I run dependency walker, not really familiar with the tool, i got a slew of "error opening file, the system cannot find the specified file" on things like API-MS-WIN-CORE-SYSINFO-L1-2-0.DLL. I also got an error, at the bottom of the dependecy's window" saying "At least one required or forwarded dependency was not found" and "Modules with different CPU types were found".

Comment: Stein, i did use the deployment tool. I was so confident on its use that i gave the software without testing,

Comment: There are many such "false positives" as indicated in the links provided above. Please do read the linked content, they speak of exactly these issues. One thing to try first might be to search system-wide for QT5core.dll and see how many versions you find.

Comment: I did read your links, in fact those i followed before i started posting here.