# Error when deploying Qt5 program on Windows

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

After building, my program runs well in the Qt5 Creator, but running the exe outside raise error

> The procedure entry point ... could not be located 
>   in the dynamic link library

Then I added the Qt5 SDK path into the system variable PATH, but this doesn't work.
After that, I tried to use the windeployqt.exe to deploy, but getting the error

> Unable to find dependent libraries of D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\Qt5Core.dll

which absolutely has the wrong path. I tried to remove all others paths in the system variable PATH, but it still doesn't work.

The environment is Windows 8.1, Qt 5.6.3, MingW 49.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QT Release build DLL procedure entry point error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11694140/qt-release-build-dll-procedure-entry-point-error) or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25524620/the-procedure-entry-point-could-not-be-located-in-dynamic-link-library or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21426326/qt-deployment-the-procedure-entry-point-could-not-be-located

Comment: The solutions in both the questions did not solve my problem.

Comment: Put essential libraries near your executable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Qt 5.0 program runs in QtCreator but not outside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15566037/qt-5-0-program-runs-in-qtcreator-but-not-outside) and https://stackoverflow.com/q/14537651/62576

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html